# What is the most effective way to fix content in older linux manpages like traceroute?

Tags: traceroute, man, manpages

Today I was reading through the manpage for traceroute when I came across this passage:

"There is a couple of additional options, intended for an advanced usage (another trace methods etc.):"

I wanted to suggest a rewording here to something like:

"There are additional options intended for advanced usage (such as alternate trace methods etc.):"

Is there any known process to fix something like this and have it propagate out to all Linux distros? This seems like it should be a basic task and yet I can't find any means to do so. There are billions of devices on Earth with this manpage installed so it strikes me as particularly odd that no one has adjusted this content since at least 11 October 2006 (the date at the end of the manpage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page came as part of a package.  Find which package it belongs to.  Follow that back upstream to your distribution, they will probably have a link to the upstream repository or developers.  Go there, submit a patch, or update following the procedures defined for that project.

So on my Debian system I mind use the following commands to figure out the upstream developer.

```
zoredache@host$ dpkg -S traceroute
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/copyright
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/CREDITS
traceroute: /usr/bin/traceroute.db
nmap: /usr/share/nmap/scripts/targets-traceroute.nse
traceroute: /usr/share/man/man1/traceroute6.db.1.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/man/man8/tcptraceroute.db.8.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/README
traceroute: /usr/bin/traceroute-nanog
traceroute: /usr/sbin/tcptraceroute.db
traceroute: /usr/bin/traceroute6.db
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/changelog.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/changelog.Debian.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/man/man1/traceroute.db.1.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/man/man1/traceroute-nanog.1.gz
traceroute: /usr/share/doc/traceroute/TODO

zoredache@host$ apt-cache show traceroute
Package: traceroute
Version: 1:2.0.18-3
Installed-Size: 175
Maintainer: Daniel Baumann <daniel.baumann@progress-technologies.net>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
Description-en: Traces the route taken by packets over an IPv4/IPv6 network
 The traceroute utility displays the route used by IP packets on their way to a
 specified network (or Internet) host. Traceroute displays the IP number and
 host name (if possible) of the machines along the route taken by the packets.
 Traceroute is used as a network debugging tool. If you're having network
 connectivity problems, traceroute will show you where the trouble is coming
 from along the route.
 .
 Install traceroute if you need a tool for diagnosing network connectivity
 problems.
Homepage: http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/
Description-md5: 8a3a47eccb961a38576ee994d96f3d2c
Tag: implemented-in::c, interface::commandline, network::routing,
 protocol::TODO, protocol::ip, role::program, scope::utility,
 use::checking, use::monitor, use::routing
Section: net
Priority: important
Filename: pool/main/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.18-3_amd64.deb
Size: 50980
MD5sum: 1e74098ae307c76eacbc60824d574fb0
SHA1: 6696a0337267788c56cfe1eb68ea7ee5b3c2129c
SHA256: 305c52bc40d8c23f34e4aee1d2e56687476a57bdd83d5f984c95f174ae388b46
```

So the uptream developer is at http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks.  I just submitted a proper ticket against the official traceroute project for Debian.